workbook open event copy consecutive numbers to consecutive cells
I am trying to create an Excel file which will be updated up on opening using the workbook open event. I make one cell a counter, which will count starting 1 when the file is opened first, then 2 when the file is opened second time and so on. I want to copy the value of the counter to the cells in row 3 starting from column H, that is, H1 = 1, I1 =2 etc. The problem is whenever I open the first time, 1 is copied to all the cells. Please see the screenshot below:

Here is my code:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i As Integer, lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, j As Integer

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(100, 1).Value = Cells(100, 1).Value + 1


For i = 2 To lastrow
    lastcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = 8 To 10
    Cells(2, j).Value = Cells(100, 1).Value
    If Cells(2, j + 1).Value = Cells(2, j).Value Then
    Exit For
    End If
    Next j
       
Next i

End Sub


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

the cells in row 3 starting from column H, that is, H1 = 1, I1 =2 etc. Do you mean H3 = 1, I3 =2? Update H3 for the 1st opening, I3 for the 2nd opening?

Was your initial code generated by AI?
You said row 3 but gave an example as H1 (so it is row 3 or 1?). I'm considering it is row 3 in my answer.
Given the initial value of cell(100,1) as 1 and cell H3 as one, try this:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim lastcol As Long

lastcol = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Cells(100, 1).Value = Cells(100, 1).Value + 1

Cells(3, lastcol + 1).Value = Cells(100, 1)

End Sub

The column counter is in row 3 so no data besides the counter should go in this row.

This is exactly I was looking, Thanks a lot. I got it, the trick was using the lastcol. You are right I made a mistake, in fact it was row 2.
